# How can i get my table values from html to servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, connection

I need to get my html table values in my servlet

Hi,

Im doing a project during my acadamic courses about sudoku website.

During my project I have encounterd a problem that I can't slove - get my table html values into my servlet. 
I have tried doing things like set hidden names and getParameterValues but none of them worked.

this is my html table

```
<table class="center">
    <% int n =9;
    for(int s = 0; s<n; s++){
        %>
    <tr>

    <% for(int f=0; f<n; f++)
    {
    %>
    <td><%  int z = SF[s][f];
        if(z==0) {%>
        <input type="text">
        <% } else { %>
        <%=SF[s][f]%>
        <%}%>
    </td  hidden name="z">
    <% } %>
    </tr  hidden name="z">
    <% } %>
</table>
```

and this is my empty servlet

```
package View;

import org.omg.CORBA.SystemException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "CheckSudokuServlet",urlPatterns =     "/CheckSudokuServlet")
public class CheckSudokuServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //tried -   String td[]=request.getParameterValues("z");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using javascript to encode the values into a url

```
var z=3;
window.location.href = "/CheckSudokuServlet?z="+z;
```

Then in your servlet you can access as so:

```
String refBgcId= request.getParameter("refBgcId").toString();
```

Comment: but my value is not var , its a table

Comment: You can still use javascript to get the contents of the table and still encode them in the url. Won't that work ?